# Expand PHP functions in strings just like variables

Tags: php, string, function

In PHP I can say

```
$noun = "bird";
$adjective = "warm;
echo <<<EOT
The $noun is very $adjective
EOT;
```

and it will output

> The bird is very warm

Is there a way to do this with functions?

```
function getNoun() { return "bird"; }
function getAdjective() { return "warm"; }
echo <<<EOT
The getNoun() is very getAdjective()
EOT;
```

and output

> The bird is very warm

Comment: Just curious, for what do you need this?

Comment: I am building a set of blogging API and I want to have a makeLink(anchor, target, format) function and put it inside of a herdoc. It has to be a heredoc string because it has multiple quotes and apostrophes. I would like it if i could embed a function in a heredoc, not just for links, but tables, pictures, posts, I think its cleaner and more readable to use an aptly named function that writes out the HTML for you than just ambiguous HTML. makePost("About HTML", "By ME", "Lorem Ipsum...,"); is so much more meaningful then <div id="post"><div id="title"><h1>AboutHTML</h1><h2>By ME</h2></div ...

Comment: Please show the code what you've done so far, probably we can help with a concrete problem of your parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store it in a variable before using it:

```
$noun = getNoun( );
$adj = getAdjective( );
echo <<<EOT
    The {$noun} is very {$adj}
EOT;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php), though they're rather frowned on upon as they're not far different from variable variables...

```
$a = 'getNoun';
$b = 'getAdjective';
echo <<<EOT
The {$a()} is very {$b()}
EOT;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "The ";
echo getNoun();
echo " is very ";
echo getVerb();
```

Or maybe even (not 100% sure):

```
echo "The " . getNoun() . " is very " . getVerb();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using variable functions, although not exactly:

```
$noun=function($type){
    return $type;
};
$adjective=function($adj){
    return $adj;
};
echo "{$noun("Robin")} was very {$adjective("Warm")}";
```